# Loop shortcut for java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Is there a way to simply type, for instance

```
loop (10){[code]}
```

and have it automatically set to

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){[code]}
```

Comment: _Why waste time say lot word when few word do trick_

Comment: In which circumstances  do you need to repeat exactly same code without using index ?

Comment: Switch to Kotlin - you can get that exact syntax to work in Kotlin.

Comment: There are IDE shortcuts for generating loops. Use those, there is no syntax help in java.

Comment: In IntelliJ (I'm sure other IDEs do this as well) you can configure shortcuts that would get you some part of the way towards this.

Comment: How much time is this actually going to save in program development?  Thinking time dominates typing time in anything significant.

Comment: its not so much time, but aggravation.  is their an IDE shortcut for say, Eclipse or Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. However, there is a shortcut when comparing index to the length of an array. Compare this...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And this...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        for (int x1 : x) {
            System.out.println(x1);
        }
    }
}
```

It isn't much of a shortcut really, but you save a few characters.